# Can I use buddies in FOB infiltrations?

Tags: metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain

Everytime I go to do an FOB infiltration mission Ocelot reminds me that I have buddies who will "fight along side me"

Although I can't figure out how to get them in?

Is it actually possible to call them in mid infiltration, seeing we have around 30 minutes odd to do an infiltration calling them in wouldn't waste much time

Comment: To be clear, you're talking about taking buddies along for FOB infiltration missions?

Comment: @twobugs what else would I be talking about, can you clarify?

Comment: @twobugs I see my error, fixed it dude

Comment: Thanks, just wanted to make sure I understood the question :)

Comment: @twobugs Sorry man, realised it could have been an actual campaign infiltration or online FOB

Comment: As far as I know, Ocelot is saying: `I'm looking forward to seeing our new companions`. He's referring to the enemy staff you can capture during an FOB mission. You can't bring a buddy along with you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge: **No.**

When infiltrating an FOB, you are not even presented with the buddy option on the sortie menu (where you can select loadout, camo, and player character). The buddy option is disabled in the iDroid Menu during an FOB mission as well, denying you the other clear option to deploy a buddy.

Comment: Let's be honest it would be an unfair advantage if the base owner turned up. They'd never be able to shoot D-Dog.

Comment: @IG_42 I was thinking more along the lines of Quiet perpetually circling the FOB in a helicopter until she shot every guard in the head. Good lord that would be obnoxious.